# Exclude zero from average result

Tags: function, t-sql

I wish to get the 12 week average of sales by day name (IE 12 weeks worth of Mondays...)
but I want to not have the zero values that may occur due to a store closure.[Example of 12 Weeks with Zero's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1vdf.png)

I wrote a script to try exclude the Zero's

```
select 
 de.[Restaurant Name]
,dd.[DayNameOfWeek]
,dd.[FinancialWC]
,AVG([Net]) OVER (PARTITION BY dw.[RedCatID],  dd.DayNameOfWeek 
ORDER BY dw.[RedCatID], dd.[FullDate] ROWS 11 PRECEDING ) as [12 Week]

from Daily_Sales_Summary dw
inner join Restaurant_View de  on de.RedCatID = dw.[RedCatID]
inner join DimDate dd on dd.[DateKey] = dw.[DateKey]
where [net] <> '0'
group by de.[Restaurant Name]
    ,dw.[RedCatID]
    ,dd.[DayNameOfWeek]
    ,dd.[FullDate]
    ,dd.[FinancialWC],[Net]
order by [Restaurant Name] asc
```

This did give me the averages I wanted but produced no results for the days with a zero value

[Query Results showing missing dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTGX4.png)

How would I go about doing this without missing the weeks with zero nulls?
I am happy to have it go back an extra week if a zero is present instead of excluding it if that is a simpler solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be a little creative here to include rows but not count them in average. Try the code below and see if it works. I haven't tested it.
Basically, what is does is redefines the denominator of calculation to give a count of rows where `[NET] <> 0`
**EDIT:** Found a simpler solution than what i originally posted

```
select 
 de.[Restaurant Name]
,dd.[DayNameOfWeek]
,dd.[FinancialWC]
,avg(nullif([Net],0)) OVER (PARTITION BY dw.[RedCatID],  dd.DayNameOfWeek 
ORDER BY dw.[RedCatID], dd.[FullDate] ROWS 11 PRECEDING ) 

 as [12 Week]

from Daily_Sales_Summary dw
inner join Restaurant_View de  on de.RedCatID = dw.[RedCatID]
inner join DimDate dd on dd.[DateKey] = dw.[DateKey]
group by de.[Restaurant Name]
    ,dw.[RedCatID]
    ,dd.[DayNameOfWeek]
    ,dd.[FullDate]
    ,dd.[FinancialWC],[Net]
order by [Restaurant Name] asc
```